# What is Bowser saying in Super Mario RPG? よって！ (includes picture)

Tags: meaning, definitions

I'm watching a YouTube video that helps learn Japanese through Mario RPG found here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRBRLmhFy-4

[image]

I think Bowser is saying something like "I hate how you always interfere!"

There's 2 parts to this question.

Part 1: About よって！ I can't figure out what this is. Is it an alternate meaning of よる or something?

Part 2: If you look up near the top left the at ん＝ない the equals sign is a standard =. But if you look at the one below with よって！＝やがって！, it has 2 small dots on top of and below the = sign. I'm not sure if this means 'similar to' or something else. I did find the definition of やがって on Jisho but I'm wanting to know more about よって.

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32584/what-does-the-word-しおって-mean

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This よって is the te-form of よる, which is an auxiliary verb that expresses disdain. Compared to やがる, よる sounds relatively old or dialectal. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78434/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28283/5010).

The te-form is sometimes used with an irritating voice to point out someone's bad or surprising behavior (I could not find the relevant definition in monolingual dictionaries). For example, a mom may say "またこんなに散らかして!" ("You've made such a mess of the room again!") to her child.

≒ is a math symbol that means "approximately equals". This is very common in Japan, but other symbols including ∼, ≃, and ≈ are used outside Japan. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Approximately_equal).